# How can develope a SAAS application in meteor?

Tags: node.js, meteor, reactjs, subdomain

We are developing a SAAS application, in which we will create sub domains for partner's accounts and need to share the same code but separate mongodb and settings for specific sub domain.

Please advice, how we can maintain common code for all sub domain and separate DB and settings.

Comment: The question is too broad to answer. A good place to start will be here: https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/building-a-saas-with-meteor-stripe-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

I think something like sandstorm might work for you.

https://sandstorm.io/

It can be self hosted (and presumably tailored to your own requirements). Some assembly required :)